# parallelize shell script

Tags: shell, parallelism

I have a following line:

```
for length in "$(ls $OUT_SAMPLE)"
do $CODES/transform_into_line2.rb -c $OUT_SAMPLE -p 0 -f $length & 
done
```

So,it should parallelize the for loop but somehow it still runs it in a sequence.
However, if I do following:

```
 $CODES/transform_into_line2.rb -c $OUT_SAMPLE -p 0 -f blabla.txt &  $CODES/transform_into_line2.rb -c $OUT_SAMPLE -p 0 -f blabla2.txt
```

It does run it in parallel. Why doesn't a for loop work?

Comment: Friendly tip: `for length in "$OUT_SAMPLE"/*`. https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/Sc2045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for length in "$(ls $OUT_SAMPLE)"
```

should be rewritten

```
for length in $(ls $OUT_SAMPLE)
```

In fact you are looping on a single value.

You can verify the values you're looping on with:

```
for length in "$(ls $OUT_SAMPLE)" ; do
  echo x$length 
done
```

Try the same without the double quotes!